# How to enter a printer command in the printer driver?

Tags: windows, printer, drivers

A client is using an Epson TM-U590 single sheet printer. This printer has a top print margin of 18.9mm, but I need to print prior to that.
There is a way to achieve this by reverse feeding the paper. To achieve this, I need to send the printer command ESC K 55 before every page.

There even is a field in the printer driver to enter commands which are then sent before every page.

My problem is: in what format do I enter this command? Decimal numbers, like 27 75 55? Or hex, like 1B 4B 37? Or in some other funky style?

Comment: did you try jsut putting in `K 55` ? ESC might not be needed, but did you just try `ESC k 55` any way..

Comment: `k55`, `\033K55` and `\x1bK55` might also be worth trying.

Comment: The printer is at the clients place, and I'm trying to figure out what to tell him to try. So I can't just try every possible combination myself :/

Comment: @Sam - Sounds like a trip to your client is in order.

Comment: Lucky me, thanks to your suggestions we broke it down fast to "1B 4B 37". The field did not allow input of K, when I entered 75 57 the printer printed the characters of the hex value of both, so I guessed to use hex and to prepend the esc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucky me, thanks to your suggestions we broke it down fast to "1B 4B 37". The field did not allow input of K, when I entered 75 57 the printer printed the characters of the hex value of both, so I guessed to use hex and to prepend the esc.